# Woocommerce conditional statement to check if user is new or returning customer

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, conditional-statements

I'm using [Woocommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce/) and want to make dollar amount minimums for each order. I was thinking I could write a conditional statement to check if a user is a new or returning customer. Is there some sort of statement I could use to check that, or maybe someone has a better suggestion?

Comment: How do you define "returning customer"? WooCommerce has an option to make guest purchases without registering. If you mean checking for a logged in user, the starting point would be `get_current_user()`.

Comment: @MSTannu Returning meaning has already purchased an item.

Comment: I don't know of any easy, built-in conditional. But you could check for a matching email address among the orders made.

Comment: @MSTannu is this something that makes sense? Anything crucial I need to include that I'm blatantly missing? http://pastebin.com/SDKnDRD1

Comment: Yes that makes sense. That function, `wc_customer_bought_product` is a good find. I'll be sure to remember it :)

Comment: @MSTannu still not working though.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what exactly goes wrong? Have you added debugging statements ( echo ... ) to see what's actually happening?

Comment: @MSTannu It's simply not working with that code. I ordered something with the correct email and when added products to the cart for a second order the min was still $100. Where would I add the echo?

Comment: I tested it in my local environment ( clean install, default theme etc ) and the function worked - asked me for $300 minimum. It did throw a warning - `wc_customer_bought_product` is missing a third argument, `product_id`. This also points out that this function tells you if that email's owner has bought that particular item, not just any item. I suggest taking a look at the function ( located in `includes/wc-user-functions.php` and ripping out parts of the database query that check for a particular product.

Comment: @MSTannu 1) Did it show $100 before you bought an item? 2) Do I always need a third argument? I want to target every single product on the site.

Comment: 1) Yes it did. 2) You need to copy that function and modify it accordingly. Btw, you should also take into account the possibility of an empty cart.

Comment: @MSTannu Thanks for staying with me. I guess I just don't understand what I am missing. How come my if statement doesn't simply work? Am I missing a step? I'm looking at the `wc-user-functions` file at the `wc_customer_bought_product` function and  I don't completely understand what it's doing or how to correct my mistakes.

Comment: Your statement does not "simply" work because that function checks if the user has already bought that particular product. In order to broaden the criteria to any product, you would need to cut out the parts of the sql query that match results to that specified product.